# Image Loading before hide Loader

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I have a problem with my angular application. I fetch data from a server, including images and would like to hide the loader animation after all is loaded. The the moment images are also loaded after loader is hidden.

Here my code for hiding loader:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.preloader.stop();
}
```

Data is fetched by a service with resolver.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: will you please provide HTML code  to understand  your problem more better

Answer (score 1):

As you are using service to get the data from the server It is very likely that your service method is returning Observable. you need **subscribe** to the observable.

**subscribe** is the function that actually **executes** the **Observable**. It takes three callback parameters :

> subscribe(success, failure, complete);

for example:

```
this.service.getDataFromServer().subscribe(
        function(response) { // executes when success
            console.log("Success" + response);
        }, 
        function(error) { // executed when failure
            console.log("Error" + error);
        }, 
        function() { // executes when completed
            console.log("Completed");
            this.preloader.stop();
        } 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is:

You should subscript to your backend API call in Angular

```
  this.yourAPICallService.subscribe((res)=>{
      //You should get all data from the server here
    },
    (error: any) => {
      //catch any error
      console.info(error);
    },
    ()=>{
      //codes should be executed after the completion of the API call
      this.preloader.stop();
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but this is not fixing the error. It it the same like using the resolver on the route to get the data. Now all informations are displayed if component is rendered, but images are popping after a short time after.

Best greetings